# webpack-dev-server adds hash query param to src file URL

Tags: webpack, query-string, webpack-dev-server, source-maps

when I open chrome debugger I can see the source files with query params like this: 
component-one.js?64f5

what is **?64f5** and how can I remove it?

webpack dev config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        path.join(__dirname, './main.js')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        publicPath: "/assets/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        }],
    },
}
```

package.json:

```
    {
      "name": "cards-framework",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "bundle.js",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack",
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.config.js -d --open --hot"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {...
      }
    }
```

Comment: if you update `One.js` does ?64f5 get updated to different value as well ?

Comment: no, it is getting updated when I save but the number does not change

Comment: Is that your full webpack config? Does the file load without the hash? It looks like you've got [hash:4] configured somewhere. Details on how to do this here: https://survivejs.com/webpack/optimizing/adding-hashes-to-filenames/ (but, sorry, no info on why it's there without you explicitly setting it)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. For me it was solved by setting:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  hash: false
}),
```